# syslog-ng multiple destinations

Tags: linux, syslog-ng

We are using `syslog-ng` to send access-log file to remote servers via `tcp`. And I already know that multiple destination can be configured to do this job, just like:

```
source s_xxx { file("/xxx/access.log"); };
destination d_one {tcp("1.2.3.4", port(1234));};  
destination d_two {tcp("1.2.3.5", port(1234));};
log {source(s_xxx); destination(d_one); destination(d_two);};
```

What I am going to figure out is that how to poll my content to these two destinations(such as round-robin). In other words, my content is either sent to `d_one` or `d_two`, not both of them.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

My scenario is very similar:  I have a syslog-ng collector that forwards messages to an analytic application.  It became overloaded and I needed to split the load.  I have no requirement for traffic on which to filter and I did not want to maintain a list of types.  I simply wanted message by message to round-robin as you are seeking.  I decided to  use mod(%) to achieve this.

Syslog-ng OSE v3.7.2:

```
destination d_net_qr1 { network("ip1"); };
destination d_net_qr2 { network("ip2"); };

filter f_qr1     { "$(% ${RCPTID} 2)"  eq "0"  };
filter f_qr2     { "$(% ${RCPTID} 2)"  eq "1"  };

log { source(s_net); filter(f_qr1); destination(d_net_qr1); };    
log { source(s_net); filter(f_qr2); destination(d_net_qr2); };
```

Answer (score 0):

syslog-ng Open Source Edition does not currently have a straightforward way to send the messages in round-robin fashion. If you want to do this for load-balancing, you can probably come up with a filter that switches between the destinations every few second using the $SEC macro and comparing macro values, see http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.6-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.6-guide-admin/html/filters-comparing.html

HTH,

Regards,

Robert